# Seeking microSD Memory with Bluetooth or WiFi

Tags: wifi, bluetooth, microsd, bluetooth-adapter

Does there exist a microSD card

[image: microSD Card]

that acts as a memory (a ¼GB is sufficient) but allows read access via Bluetooth or even WiFi? I have a very sensitive (low light) camera

[image: siOnyx Aurora Sport]

that, under only starlight, can record color video on an internally stored microSD card; the camera is water resistant and the microSD slot is not accessible. I'd like to be able to read that video as it is being recorded, using the camera as an electronic finder on my astronomical telescope.

So far, I've been through about 300 of the listed 2000 Amazon entries for microSD without any joy. ;S

Thank you.

Comment: Toshiba -now Kioxia- has the "FlashAir" line of SD cards with built-in WiFi. I somehow doubt that similar products exist in the even smaller microSD form factor.https://www.toshiba-memory.com/products/toshiba-wireless-sd-cards-flashair-w-04/

Comment: It would have helped if you had told us which camera.

Answer (score 0):

None found by deep search in Amazon and elsewhere. Also used 'MicroSDHC' the new name for microSD, as search term, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

There is a guide [here](https://nerdtechy.com/best-wifi-sd-card) (which says it is for 2021).  ***BUT***, it covers SD cards only, not micro SD, and says "`While full-sized SD cards can use WiFi technology, it’s not yet available on Micro SD cards`". Also, the largest one listed is only 128 gB :-(

[This listing](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Tonsee-Adapter-Wireless-Memory-Camera/dp/B0164VG6KG) on Amazon ***UK***, is no longer in stock, but did handle micro SD, so could be inspiration for a search on "`Tonsee Micro SDHC Card to WIFI SD Card Adapte`". You can also try [this store](https://grenada.desertcart.com/products/50370326-tonsee-micro-sdhc-card-to-wifi-sd-card-adapter-wireless-memory-card-for-dv-camera) where it is also currently out of stock; but, maybe contact them asking for a similar item?

[This one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/QUMOX-CompactFlash-Memory-Adapter-Camera/dp/B07FQHPSKS) is still in stock at GBP £15.20 (approx US $21 / Eur 18), and looks promising. It has 42% 5 star reviews & 23% 1 star, so, read the comments.

[Here's one](https://www.ebay.co.uk/p/27023974576) for sale on eBay for GBP £  17.49. Of course the listing won't last, but try searching for "`WiFi Wireless Micro SD TF Flash Card SDHC Memory Cordless Adapter for Camera`". The seller does not have an eBay shop, there are several similar items listed.